How can I prevent the browser from autocompleting for a primeng p-password?
This is a problem that I have been researching for some time and have not been able to find a solution. I have a PrimeNG p-password and I don't want it to fill in the password.
<p-password autocomplete="new-password" [toggleMask]="true" [feedback]="false"/>
Using autocomplete="new-password" works to prevent autocompletion as soon as the component loads, but when I click on input it still suggests a saved password.


What can I do to prevent the password from being filled in when I click on input?

We can autocomplete="off" to prevent the suggestions.
<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
  <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="value" id="email" name="email" />
</div>

<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
  <input
    type="text"
    pInputText
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    id="email"
    name="email"
    autocomplete="off"
  />
</div>

<p-password autocomplete="off" [toggleMask]="true" [feedback]="false" />

Stackblitz Demo

The problem continues, using autocomplete="off" is worse, as soon as the component loads the password is already filled in automatically, if you use autocomplete="new-password" it only fills in when you click on input. But I don't want it to be filled in even when I click on input.
